# How to route to a different VueJS component on execution of a function in an external script?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

When I click on the below route link, I navigate to the contact page.

```
 <router-link to="/contact">contact</router-link>
```

But I want to route automatically rather than clicking on route link on the execution of a function.

I want to do so because I want to have some conditions in the function & if they are satisfied, then only routing is done.

The functions I am calling is in an external script. (es5 syntax).

On adding `router.push('contact')` in the external script I am getting an error:  `router not defined !` in my external script!

How can I add the router function to my external script?

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html

Comment: Helpful ! But, error! `router not defined !` in my external script! How can I add router function to my external script?

Comment: should I `add a function in my component` that `calls my global script function`? and if `it returns true`, I should `route` to different component?

Comment: Just set `window.location.href` directly.  The Vue "router" function is obviously not going to be available in non-Vue code.

Comment: wont `window.location.href` refresh the whole page?

Comment: Not if the URL you're routing to is the same literal "page".

Comment: Oh, normally if I route from `home -> contact` the `page doesn't refresh`, it's a `SPA`.Only the `components` that `differ` in both the components are `changed`. The `DOM` doesn't get `destroyed completely`.

Comment: Even if i am using `router.push()` inside view method , error -> `router is not defined`. `this.router` also doesn't work either .

Comment: Where is `const router = new VueRouter(...)` defined in relation to the external code you are trying to use `router.push` from? If you import the `router` into the script that needs it you can use it. Or, `window.router = new VueRouter(...)`. Also, inside Vue it would be `this.$router`.

Comment: Have you read https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html ?

Comment: Inside .vue I got dynamic route working.Found my mistake by suggestions here!Thanks. `Navigation-guards` was `helpful`. Maybe declaring `route globally` may give access of route to external script.Will try & tell the result.